# Loading multiple CSV files into PostgreSQL Table

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have multiple CSV files. Those CSV files are the log files created as a result of running a Windows batch file. The location of these CSV files lies on the server and I want all these CSV files to copy from the server to a particular table (say import_error_table, which I had already created in PostgreSQL).

How to accomplish this using PostgreSQL?

I tried running a Windows batch file which is shown below.

[image]

And in the above snapshot, there is an exe file to convert a shapefile to pgsql. I would like to know is there any specific exe for converting CSV to pgsql.

I had run the above code as a batch file. The prep.sql file is created with (0KB size). But also schema was not created in the PostgreSQL.

```
for %%f in (*.csv) do \\192.158.5.170\working\PostGIS\psql.exe -p -k -s 32643 %%f CSV_Logs.%%~nf > prep_%%~nf.sql
set PGPASSWORD=rpc123
for %%f in (prep_*.sql) do \\192.158.5.170\working\PostGIS\psql -h 192.158.5.170  -p 5432 -d NPCL_test -U postgres -f %%f
```

The result of which is prep.sql files created but schema was not created in PostgreSQL.

[image]

Comment: psql already is an executable. When I do this I just wrap a bunch of calls to `psql -c "copy some_table from some_csv csv" db_name` in the shell.

Comment: Answers below do work but assume you have the tables created already. Another tool which can a) create a CREATE TABLE expression based on a CSV and b) load the CSV into a table *and* create the table in the same expression is CSVKit - I have a tutorial here, and I think you might find a way to utilize the comand on multiple files using Python: https://github.com/dpsspatial/Installation-Instructions/blob/master/csvkit.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two examples of how this can be done:

Just put the batchfile in the same folder where the csv-files are:

for copy from local machine to local database:

```
for %%f in (*.csv)  do psql -d your_database_name -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 -c "\COPY public.yourtablename FROM '%%~dpnxf' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
pause
```

You can also run the batchfile on your computer and send the content of the CSV-Files to the remote database. Just put the csv-files on your local computer and the batchfile in the same folder. Content of the batchfile:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set PGPASSWORD=yourpassword



for %%f in (*.csv)  do psql -d your_database -h your_server_ip -U postgres -p 5432 -c "\COPY public.yourtablename FROM '%%~dpnxf' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"

pause
endlocal
```

Just tested it on my machine and works both: local PostgreSQL on Windows7 and remote PostgreSQL on Ubuntu Linux.

PS: Using the \COPY instead of just COPY is important if you want to read the local csv's and copy them to the remote database.

Comment: Great!  my problem solved. your code works.

Comment: I had edited my post. Since there is a new problem in running the batch file.

Comment: You don't have to create sql-files.all you need is adapt my batch file template so it fits to your server-ip, database name and so on.don't insert any other commands

Comment: Before loading my CSV files into a table. I need to create a table right for loading CSV files? That's what the above code snippet (prep.sql) does

Comment: well in you question you said "to a particular table (say import_error_table, which i had already created in postgreSQL"). You can't create a table using CSV. You have to manually create the table and its columns, because a csv does not contain information about which data type should be used for each column.

Comment: Yeah I do agree. But table can also be created using windows command Script. The First snapshot which I had attached above in the post create a table called "fme_csv_logfiles_import" provided if there are shapefiles in the folder. My doubt is is there any specific exe application in postgis that creates a table and loads csv files into postgreSQL similar to shape2pgsql or raster2pgsql or the only option in case of CSV file is to manually create tables and then import.

Comment: in the csv-files there is no information about which datatype should be used for the columns. with ogr2ogr and csvt-files you can set some datatypes but a better alternative would be to use dbf instad of csv. these you can import directly. ( or create the create-table-sql-statements with the batchfile that creates your csv's.

Comment: Well, Thank you Thomas for your clear explanation. I got clear and your code works fine when I manually create a table and then import CSV files.

Comment: One of my colleague tried the below command.He got Logon failure: Unknown username or bad password.What is wrong in it?                                                     
@echo off
setlocal
set PGPASSWORD=rpc123



for %%f in (*.csv)  do \\192.158.5.170\working\PostGIS\psql.exe -d NPCL_test -h 192.158.5.170 -U postgres -p 5432 -c "\COPY public.yourtablename FROM '%%~dpnxf' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"

pause
endlocal